# Difference between p in a rails view and puts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie in Rails. I created a controller and a action. In the corresponding view I used 
 <%= puts "asd" %> once and <%= p "asd" %> the other time.

In case id puts it shows on the console and in case of p it is rendered as HTML. What is the possible reason?

Comment: Tip for the newbie: "Rails" isn't spelt in ALL CAPITALS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`puts` calls the method `to_s`
`p` calls the method `inspect`

```
class Foo
  def to_s
    "In #to_s"
  end
  def inspect
    "In #inspect"
  def
def
```

Semantically, to_s is meant to output the representation of the object to the user, and inspect to hint about the internal properties of the object (kinda like python's `repr`), but that's just a convention.

If you want to inspect something **in your HTML** use `<%= debug "something" %>`

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find that the `p` method outputs to the console as well, but the reason why it's "rendered as HTML" is because the `p` method returns the value passed in, where `puts` does not.

`p` is the shorter version of `puts something.inspect` and is very useful for debugging and that's about it. For outputting strings to the console, it's more preferrable to use `puts`.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely related to the question, but I advocate the use of awesome_print ("ap" vs. "p")

https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

It does have support in views as a Rails plugin, but I mostly use it for the console.